# Render from angularjs directive via eventRender Fullcalendar

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar

Is there a way to dynamically Render a template from angularjs directive via eventRender Fullcalendar ?

What I want to achieve is something like below:

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {

  var template = '<my-directive></my-directive>';

  element.find('.fc-event').append(template);

  scope.$apply();
}
```

Following [Documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender)

The eventRender callback function can modify element.

For example, it can change its appearance via jQuery’s .css().

On eventRender insert the css classes with

```
eventRender: function (event, element) {

    element.addClass(event.class)
}
```

[Documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender) on this topic is not broad in the subject.

It doesn't give any example of changing the template via Angularjs directives 
and doesn't tell if there is any limitaion for template 
to keep it treated by FullCalendar as event.

[MyCodePen](https://codepen.io/adier/pen/NoogPq)

[EDITED_Code_Pen](https://codepen.io/adier/pen/jddjqq)

Comment: you don't `return` from eventRender. That doesn't do anything useful. If you want to modify the event's appearance you have to alter the `element` object provided in the callback.

Comment: Thank you ADyson. I updated my question according to your advice. Should I use $compile service in that case ?

Comment: Sorry I don't know anything about Angular, I only know about fullCalendar and standard JS. P.S. "doesn't work" isn't really an adequate description of a problem...have you tried to do any detailed debugging?

Comment: Thanks again ADyson. I'll update my question with a codePen.

Comment: updated the quesion.

Comment: I suspect the issue in your codePen is that `$scope.$apply` appears to be asynchronous - it relies on a callback to actually execute the changes. So by the time the callback runs, the eventRender function has already finished and your chance to amend the element has gone. Again, I don't know Angular but I think you need to find a way to apply your changes such that they run immediately inside EventRender, not waiting for another callback which happens at some later time.

Comment: First of all  ADyson many Thanks, I made another change to my codePen I updated my code one more time according to your advice and it works now it was necessary to replace .fc-event with .fc-content but now I have a problem with the background panel in blue how to get rid of him so that esthetically speaking, the drop of an event will be done in a more beautiful way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- add $compile to your controller

2- in eventRender make as bellow :

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {


     var compiled = $compile('<div your-directive></div>')($scope);

     element.find('.fc-content').replaceWith(compiled);

 },
```

[workingCodePen](https://codepen.io/adier/pen/jddjqq)